# gcc doesn't accept out-of-line definition of member with non-type template parameter defined via nested templated using clause

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++14

The title seems convoluted but our test-case is actually a minimal example for a real case.

We have code for which we want to choose implementation of a method based on the template parameter. We during clean up we defined conditional `enable_if_t` with using clause, and as next step wanted to put definition out of line, this produced following code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct A {
    template <typename U>
    using is_int_or_float = std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<U, int>::value || std::is_same<U, float>::value >;

    template<typename U = T, is_int_or_float<U>* = nullptr >
    void f();
    template<typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<U,std::string>::value >* = nullptr >
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename U, typename A<T>::template is_int_or_float<U>* >
void  A<T>::f(){
    std::cout << "f for int or float\n";
}

template <typename T>
template<typename U, typename std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<U,std::string>::value >*>
void A<T>::f() {
    std::cout << "f for string\n";
}

int main () {
    A<int> a_int;
    A<std::string> a_string;
    A<float> a_float;
    a_int.f();
    a_string.f();
    a_float.f();
    a_float.f<std::string>();
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc does not accept it while clang does: https://godbolt.org/g/Gfm1tw

gcc (and icc) complain that there is no valid prototype for method defined with `is_int_or_float`.

I am not sure whether clang is too promiscuous or gcc should be able to get past the dependent type.

The code works if we switch`typename A<T>::template is_int_or_float<U>` for it's definition:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<U, int>::value || std::is_same<U, float>::value >* >
void  A<T>::f(){
    std::cout << "f for int or float\n";
}
```

Does using `using` change some rules about type matching, or should gcc be able to consume it?

*EDIT:* Thanks to input from [@VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) we figured out, that the difference is in the `typename` keyword in the out-of-line declaration `typename A<T>::template is_int_or_float<U>*`. Removing it makes gcc compile and clang refuse the code.

So the question can be rephrased and simplified: Is typename required or this allowed in this case?

Comment: SFINAE Substitution Failure Is Not An Error if the substitution happens in the direct context of the function template declaration

Comment: Few changes make [gcc accept this code and clang reject it](https://godbolt.org/g/MAz3Go). Alternatively defining `is_int_or_float` ouside of main template (which is probably a good idea anyway) will [fix everything](https://godbolt.org/g/GFnKj1).

Comment: @VTT Great input. The template argument in your example can be empty, thus, the only difference is the typename keyword. I think this allows to greatly improve and simplify the question. Is the typename there required or disallowed. I know there are at least few ways to make it compile, but the two compilers disagree, and one is probably non-conformant in this case.

Comment: This is handled by the age-old http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2 . Also relevant and (I think) applies to your case (except in your case it's the template parameter list.. but that's just a syntactic difference): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#560

Comment: Note the submitter of the second one is Greg Comeau. The Comeau compiler is based on the EDG frontend, which ICC also uses.

Comment: So, to my understanding it's not a bug in neither compiler, but a bit grey area in the standard. One could argue, that gcc is right and the keyword is not needed (as described [#560](open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#560)) but the common consesus (looking at the proposed solutions) is that it should be required because the type is dependent on the template argument. Would you mind posting this as an answer? I don't think there is a better one in current state of things.

Comment: I don't know for sure and I'm reluctant of posting informed guesses, so I'm better off leaving comments. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1041090/richard-smith would know for sure, as he works for Google on LLVM/Clang and the C++ committee if you pointed him to this question.