# What are the rules for out-of-line definitions of constrained member templates?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider the following [code](https://godbolt.org/z/hYnfWP):

```
template <typename T>
struct S 
{
    template <typename = void>
    static constexpr bool B = true;

    template <std::enable_if_t<S<T>::template B<>, int> = 0>
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
template <std::enable_if_t<S<T>::template B<>, int>>
void S<T>::f() {}
```

gcc accepts this, but clang rejects it with:

```
error: out-of-line definition of 'f' does not match any declaration in 'S<T>'
```

This has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448353/gcc-doesnt-accept-out-of-line-definition-of-member-with-non-type-template-param) about before, but there is no answer there.

---

On the other hand, if `B` is not a template, and I write this [code](https://godbolt.org/z/eYzWcG):

```
template <typename T>
struct S 
{
    static constexpr bool B = true;

    template <std::enable_if_t<S<T>::B, int> = 0>
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
template <std::enable_if_t<S<T>::B, int>>
void S<T>::f() {}
```

clang accepts this, but gcc rejects the code with:

```
error: no declaration matches 'void S<T>::f()'
```

---

So are either of these snippets valid?

Comment: Is it allowed to access `S<T>::B`. I would say no because S<T> is incomplete at that point.

Answer (score 2):

During the definition of `S<X>` it is an incomplete type. And the class member access operator requires a complete type.

But you could solve the situation with the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S {

    template <typename = void>
    static constexpr bool B = true;

    template <
        typename TX = T,
        std::enable_if_t<S<TX>::template B<>, int> = 0>
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename TX, std::enable_if_t<S<TX>::template B<>, int>>
void S<T>::f() {}

//-----------

template <typename T>
struct S2 {

    static constexpr bool B = true;

    template <
        typename TX = T,
        std::enable_if_t<S2<TX>::B, int> = 0>
    void f();
};

template <typename T>
template <typename TX, std::enable_if_t<S2<TX>::B, int>>
void S2<T>::f() {}
```

Comment: So your claim is `template <std::enable_if_t<S<T>::B, int> = 0>
    void f();` is the problem?  Is it an ill-formed program, no diagnostic required, or are the compilers failing to provide a diagnostic?

Comment: Yes it is. But even if it would be allowed it would not work because the enable_if_t expression does not depend on a deduced type. If B would be false it would cause a compile time error (enable_if<...> has no member type...).

Comment: Can you point out where in the standard it is defined as "ill-formed program, no diagnostic required"?  (there are, I think, less than a dozen times that is invoked in the standard).  I ask because this is a [tag:language-lawyer] question.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is correct. `S<TX>` seems as incomplete or not, as `S<T>`. Regardless, could you point to the rules that say the snippets in the question are wrong?

Comment: If `S<T>::B` was the problem then [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5rO6QmaOloHk1kCC) wouldn't compile. Yet, `S<T>::B` doesn't compile only out-of-class, when `S` *is* complete. Also inside `S` you can replace `S<T>::B` with `B` for the same effect. Anyway, the rules are pretty simple (see [temp.type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.type)). Looks like a gcc bug to me.